# trouble with onkeydown event block all input except numeric, but allow enter to submit form?

Tags: php, onkeydown

I am having trouble with a form that displays results drawn out of a mysql database, based on a user supplied string.

An order form, so to say. And in this form there is a quantity field. I have tried to use javascript to block all input except for numeric values. Along with this though, I have disabled the enter key functionality.

I know that this keycode is 23. But how do I allow a user may press enter to submit the form, working with the following peice of code:

```
onkeydown="return ( event.ctrlKey || event.altKey 
                || (47<event.keyCode && event.keyCode<58 && event.shiftKey==false) 
                || (95<event.keyCode && event.keyCode<106)
                || (event.keyCode==8) || (event.keyCode==9) 
                || (event.keyCode>34 && event.keyCode<40) 
                || (event.keyCode==46) )"
```

Any input with this would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might help you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $('#numeric').keydown(function(e) {
                    return ((e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57) || e.keyCode == 13)
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <input type="text" id="numeric" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi and thanks, but there appears to be some kind of syntax error with this line: `$('#numeric').keydown(function(e) {`